# Transform different objects into date formats

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a DF that contains start date and end date in different formats. And those dates are like character.

```
KEY <- c (12,55,889)
START <- c ("2019-01-03T16: 59: 51", "2018-12-31T12: 03: 13", "2019-01-07", "2019-01-08")
END <- c ("2019-01-10T13: 10: 00", "2019-01-05T12: 00: 00", "2019-01-09", "2019-01-12")
DF <- data.frame (KEY, START, END)
```

How would I do to disregard time and turn them into DATE. My goal is to make a difference between dates. I want the following result:

```
KEY <- c (12,55,889,896)
START <- c ("2019-01-03", "2018-12-31", "2019-01-07", "2019-01-08")
END <- c ("2019-01-10", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-09", "2019-01-12")
DIF <- c (7,5,2,4)
DF <- data.frame (KEY, START, END, DIF)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the data in the Note at the end we can use `as.Date` as it ignores any junk at the end.  No packages are used.

```
transform(DF, START = as.Date(START), END = as.Date(END))
##   KEY      START        END
## 1  12 2019-01-03 2019-01-10
## 2  55 2018-12-31 2019-01-05
## 3 889 2019-01-07 2019-01-09
## 4  10 2019-01-08 2019-01-12
```

### Note

I have added a 10 at the end of `KEY` since there were only 3 elements vs. 4 for the other columns.

```
KEY <- c(12,55,889,10)
START <- c("2019-01-03T16: 59: 51", "2018-12-31T12: 03: 13", "2019-01-07", "2019-01-08")
END <- c("2019-01-10T13: 10: 00", "2019-01-05T12: 00: 00", "2019-01-09", "2019-01-12")
DF <- data.frame(KEY, START, END)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(dplyr)
library(anytime)
DF1 <- DF %>%
          mutate_at(vars(START, END), anydate)
DF1
#  KEY      START        END
#1  12 2019-01-03 2019-01-10
#2  55 2018-12-31 2019-01-05
#3 889 2019-01-07 2019-01-09
#4 896 2019-01-08 2019-01-12

str(DF1)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ KEY  : num  12 55 889 896
# $ START: Date, format: "2019-01-03" "2018-12-31" "2019-01-07" "2019-01-08"
# $ END  : Date, format: "2019-01-10" "2019-01-05" "2019-01-09" "2019-01-12"
```

---

In the `devel` version of `dplyr`, we can combine `mutate` with `across`

```
DF %>% 
    mutate(across(c(START, END), anydate))
#  KEY      START        END
#1  12 2019-01-03 2019-01-10
#2  55 2018-12-31 2019-01-05
#3 889 2019-01-07 2019-01-09
#4 896 2019-01-08 2019-01-12
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(KEY = c(12, 55, 889, 896), START = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("2018-12-31T12: 03: 13", "2019-01-03T16: 59: 51", 
"2019-01-07", "2019-01-08"), class = "factor"), END = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("2019-01-05T12: 00: 00", "2019-01-09", 
"2019-01-10T13: 10: 00", "2019-01-12"), class = "factor")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```